# Make view clickable underneath recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve a similar look like the Google Play Store App



[image]

For now I got this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="200dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Looks great but since the Recyclerview is overlapping the ImageView, it's not clickable anymore. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni Tried that already. Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of scrolling activity template in the android studio it has similar behaviour to what you want to do.
and put `ImageView` in `AppBarLayout`
and handle the click events like any other view.

this won't give you the exact behaviour of google play app but if it's the eases way to do it.
if you want the exact behaviour I know an open source library that do that let me know if you want it and I will search for it.

[image]